# Instantiating class with NO constructor results in 'does not contain constructor which takes 0 arguments' error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to instantiate a `FacetResult` from the Azure.Search.Documents library:

```
var facetResult = new Azure.Search.Documents.Models.FacetResult();
```

VS is telling me the class does not contain a constructor with zero arguments. When I check the metadata for the class - no constructor.

Looking at [the docs for the class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.models.facetresult?view=azure-dotnet) seems to confirm that there is no constructor - so what's the issue?

[I'm having the same issue with other library classes with no constructors such as Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobItem, while classes which appear to explicitly declare a parameterless constructor seem fine, such as System.Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzTa2.png)

Any help with this would be much appreciated, it's blocking my unit tests!

Comment: The base class ctor requires at least one argument

Comment: Your title says "inheriting from a class that...".  I don't see any inheritance in the code you show

Comment: There's always a constructor. If it's not there in the source code, a parameterless constructor is automatically created by the compiler.

Comment: @Flydog57 brain fart, sorry. Changed 'inheriting' to 'instantiating', cheers.

Comment: At @MarkBenningfield which base class exactly? Azure.Search.Documents.Models.FacetResult has no base class, or am I mistaken?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.models.facetresult?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: The github docs show the constructor is `internal` [github repo docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/0ebd32c0359bcd7a20b1708683c323a0b26b618a/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/api/Azure.Search.Documents.netstandard2.0.cs#L2286).

Comment: What does Intellisense do when you type the opening parenthesis in `new FacetResult(`?  Does it suggest you can close it without parameters, does it give you any hints?  Have you looked at the class metadata?  Maybe there's something like an `internal` constructor, only allowing instances of objects defined in the same assembly to create one of these (it is a `Result` of something afterall)

Comment: Thanks all. Seems the ctor is internal so @quaabaam you were correct. Couldn't see this in the metadata or the docs, next time I'll check github.

Comment: SO won't let me tag more than one user in a single comment, thanks to @Flydog57 too for the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors for this class are internal.
Instances are likely created and returned by factories.

```
//src code @ https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/
namespace Azure.Search.Documents.Models
{
    /// <summary> A single bucket of a facet query result. Reports the number of documents with a field value falling within a particular range or having a particular value or interval. </summary>
    public partial class FacetResult
    {
        /// <summary> Initializes a new instance of FacetResult. </summary>
        internal FacetResult()
        {
            AdditionalProperties = new ChangeTrackingDictionary<string, object>();
        }

        /// <summary> Initializes a new instance of FacetResult. </summary>
        /// <param name="count"> The approximate count of documents falling within the bucket described by this facet. </param>
        /// <param name="additionalProperties"> Additional Properties. </param>
        internal FacetResult(long? count, IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> additionalProperties)
        {
            Count = count;
            AdditionalProperties = additionalProperties;
        }
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/4162f6fa2445b2127468b9cfd080f01c9da88eba/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/src/Generated/Models/FacetResult.cs

Comment: That'll be it then, thank you. I couldn't glean this from the metadata in VS or from the MSDN docs - in future I'll be sure to check github. Cheers @lidqy.

Comment: You could still create it using reflection. Just seems to carry  2-3 properties as sort of a poco, no logic hidden.

Comment: In case anyone gets here for exactly the same reason I asked the question, instantiating or mocking a FacetResult for testing purposes, check out the SearchModelFactory, which is designed for exactly that: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Search.Documents/1.0.0-preview.4/api/Azure.Search.Documents.Models/Azure.Search.Documents.Models.SearchModelFactory.html